# How to call additional npm start script in Angular 2 cli config?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Two projects:

1. Main angular 2 project using the cli/ng serve: Throws up on localhost:4200.
2. Reveal.js using npm start: Throws up on localhost:8000

I would like to do something like:

- ng serve
- Would you like the reveal.js too? (Y/n)

OR add a parameter on the end.

- ng serve -r

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shell script (e.g.myShellScript.bat) that would ask the question "Would you like the reveal.js too? (Y/n)" and run npm start if the user answered Y.

Then declare a command in the scripts section of your package.json:

"startMyServers": "myShellScript.bat && ng serve"

Then run this command:

npm run startMyServers